# 2.8 Why are collections grayed out? How can I open them?

Tags: interface

I've bought Cup models from Internet.

When opening .blend file I get Blender's Interface changed. To avoid this I've unchecked "Load UI" on opening the file.

But now I cannot see the objects of the project (I can see and render them when opening the file and leaving "Load UI" checked).

"Collection 1" on the "Objects Panel" (Don't know if it is it's name). is grayed out.

**cup-models.blend with LOAD UI:**

[image]

**cup-models.blend without LOAD UI:**

[image]

**Blender 2.8**:

[image]

Comment: Can you enable the "eye" icon in the outliner? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MTtT.gif

Comment: Nope. I can't do that

Comment: Are you using the latest version of 2.8?

Comment: Yes. The one relased on the 21st. I'll put an image of the version on my question.

Comment: And there is YET another (apart from "Exclude from View Layer" and the simple "Hide") hiding option which is... hiding... under Right Click - Visibility - Disable in Viewports. That greys the thing out, too. It also seems to default to this when an older .blend was opened in 2.8 that contained multiple things in not-visible (at the time of saving) layers.

Comment: @BuzzKirill f'ing christ thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr: Your collections are set to be excluded from the scene.**

This is the Blender 2.80 replacement for enabling/disabling layers. Instead of selecting or deselecting a couple of layers in your viewport, you set your collection to be excluded from the viewport.

Go to the Outliner, left-click on one or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + left-click on multiple collections, right-click to open the Menu and go to "View Layer" and click "Clear Exclude" - alternatively hit the Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> while your mouse pointer is within the Outliner.

[image: clear exclude]

Comment: For some reason this feature was removed in one of the release candidates, and then added again (but renamed) in the final 2.8 release. The latest version has it, but it's called `Enable in Viewports`/`Disable in Viewports` in the same sub-menu. However, the `ALT+E` shortcut doesn't work anymore.

EDIT: it's not in the `View Layer` sub-menu anymore, it's in the `Visibility` sub-menu.

Comment: The answer should be updated with your comment.

Comment: It's still the same in Blender 2.81a and 2.82. If everything is greyed out, move your mouse pointer within the outliner, hit Alt+E and your objects should reappear. If one or more collections are visible in the outliner, right-click on one collection and you'll find the "View Layer" submenu.

Comment: The fix mentioned above didn't work for me, but led me in the right direction: My whole collection was enabled, but some objects were still invisible. I fixed this by selecting those objects and navigating to Properties => Object Properties => Visibility => "Show in Viewport".

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggestions in comments work for me. These objects remain grayed out after updating my blend file to 2.82.7

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using version 2.93.5 .. this is where I made the grey game object  visible  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Blender 3.2.1:

1. Find the grayed-out "Collection" in the Outliner.
2. Right-click.
3. *Visibility*.
4. *Enable in Viewports*.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone looking for this answere, none of the upper solutions worked for me, what I did was moving all meshes that where greyed out to the default activated Collection, there is one that show everything inside normally. Just move all your mesh to that one and then separate everything in new Collections.