# Objects in outliner grayed out

Tags: 3d-view, outliner, visibility

I have been using blender 2.79 and recently downloaded 2.8.
I was modelling a scene in blender 2.79 and when opening it up in 2.8 most of my objects are greyed out.
Everything is enabled in the viewport, nothing is hidden.
One object is still visible but the rest are not.

I have tried using the filters, changing the visibility in the collections to restore visibility.

The weird thing is, blender is saying that they aren't hidden but can't be seen in the renderer or in the viewport.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

[image: Grayed out objects in outliner]

[image]

Comment: Please upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Related  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135114/2-8-why-are-collections-grayed-out-how-can-i-open-them   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8

Comment: batFINGER, sadly, that post does not solve my problem, and I am unable to post any comments to ask further questions. That is why I created this post. I have already looked for answers before posting and no previous posts are able to help, sadly.

Comment: @Jackdaw I have uploaded my blender file, have you had any luck at understanding my problem?

Comment: @dval answer was it for me, not the accepted one

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The objects are disabled in "Viewports". You need to enable the Restriction Toggle and then enable them there to make them visible.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to Jackdaw's answer:

The view settings are also available from the Object Properties tab under 'Visibility'.

But, it seems if you want to toggle these settings for multiple objects, that can only be done in the Outliner.

[image: view-able states object panel]

Comment: Should be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

To add another possible scenario:

Objects will be grayed out in the outliner also when they are linked to an object from a different collection.

Let me show you:

The object *Foil door.001* is gray because it is in the main scene collection and at the same time it is linked to the empty *DoorHinge.000*, which is in the collection *Doors*.

Therefore *Foil door.001* is actually visible in the outliner twice (see image).
Both entries refer to the same object. The gray entry only indicates the relation to the empty *DoorHinge.000*.
[image: Outliner example]
I hope this also helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Object Data->Normals->Auto smoth and check them...Helped me!